# merge sort implementation in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I was trying to implement the merge sort algorithm given in CLRS 3rd edition.
Instead of using sentinel values, I have checked for the bounds in the merge operation.

Following is my merge sort implementation

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void merge(int [],int p,int q ,int r);
void mergeSort(int [],int p,int r);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int input[10];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        input[i] = (rand()%100)+10;
    }
    mergeSort(input,0,9);
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i = 0 ;i <10; i++){
        cout<<input[i]<<"\t";

    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void mergeSort(int  input[],int lower, int higher)
{
    if(lower<higher){
        int mid = (lower + higher)/2;
        mergeSort(input,lower,mid);
        mergeSort(input,mid+1,higher);
        merge(input,lower,mid,higher);
    }
}
void merge(int input[], int lower, int mid , int higher)
{
    int sizeLeft = mid - lower +1;

    int sizeRight = higher - mid;

    int *leftArray = new int(sizeLeft);

    int *rightArray  = new int(sizeRight);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeLeft ; i++){
        leftArray[i] = input[i+lower];
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < sizeRight ; j++){
        rightArray[j] = input[mid+j+1];
    }

    int i = 0 ;
    int j =0;

    for (int k  = lower ; k <= higher ; k++){

        if(leftArray[i]<=rightArray[j] || j>higher){
            input[k]= leftArray[i];
            i =  i + 1;

        }else if(rightArray[j]< leftArray[i] || i>mid){
            input[k] = rightArray[j];
            j = j+1;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output for every run of the program

`25      0       0       31      0       0       45      0       87      0`

Basically I am randomly generating 10 numbers and copying them to an array and I sort the array using merge sort.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

`--EDIT--`

I made the following changes after going through the debugger and I got the correct answer.
In the  merge operation, I changed it to this:

```
void merge(int input[], int lower, int mid , int higher)
{
    int sizeLeft = mid - lower +1;

    int sizeRight = higher - mid;

    int *leftArray = new int[sizeLeft];

    int *rightArray  = new int[sizeRight];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeLeft ; i++){
        leftArray[i] = input[i+lower];
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < sizeRight ; j++){
        rightArray[j] = input[mid+j+1];
    }

    int i = 0 ;
    int j =0;

    for (int k  = lower ; k <= higher ; k++){

        if((i+lower)>mid){
            input[k]= rightArray[j++];
        }else if((j+mid+1)>higher){
            input[k] = leftArray[i++];
        }else if(leftArray[i]<= rightArray[j]){
            input[k] = leftArray[i++];
        }else{
            input[k] = rightArray[j++];
        }
    }

    delete [] leftArray;
    delete [] rightArray;
}
```

Comment: So you have stepped through all the code in the debugger?

Comment: yes I stepped through the code in the debugger but I can only see the first item in the input array. I dont know what other items in the array are. I am using netbeans.

Comment: Try smaller test cases, like one- and two-element arrays, and look at what `merge` does.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I tried smaller test cases and found out the problem in logic. Finally, I have the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have problems with your algorithm but what stands out is a very bad memory handling bug.

When you say:

```
int *leftArray = new int(sizeLeft);
```

You allocate memory for  **single** `int` and initialize it with the value of `sizeLeft`. That's clearly not what you want. If you want to allocate memory for an **array** of `int` you should say:

```
int *leftArray = new int[sizeLeft];
```

Note the square brackets instead of parentheses.

You also don't release the memory before the function returns so you leak memory every time it's called. To free the memory you'll need to do:

```
delete [] leftArray;
```

Having said that, this is C++ and there are better ways to have a dynamic array such as `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank  you for your valuable insight. There was a problem with the logic and the also the dynamic array initialization as you mentioned. After correcting the array initialization and logic error. I have the correct answer..